# Get DataTable values from code behind to client side using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need help on getting a particular datatable values from the server to the client using javascript.

Ex. 
In my class which is Countries.aspx.cs I have this somewhere on my code say on the page load.

```
DataTable dtbCountries = Repository.GetAllCountries;
```

my dtbCountries now contains this record

```
ID  Country
1   HongKong
2   Japan
3   Korea
```

In my webform I want to get the values of my dtbCountries using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // my code here to get the dtbCountries values
</script>
```

What should I do? Or what's the best thing to do to expose my dtbCountries in the client.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options for this. First of all, I assume that what you need is the actual data and not any functionality given by the DataTable object, so you better create an entity (could be a `struct`) to store the table's data —it must be marked with `Serializable` attribute.

One of your options is to encapsulate retrieving it in a *Page Method*. These methods are exposed to JavaScript transparently (i.e., they have the same syntax as in the code behind). These methods need to be `static`, and be marked with the `PageMethod` attribute.

Another option would be to "write" the content of your table in the HTML in JSON format (a notation to represent objects in JavaScript).

**Edit 2**: The way to serialize something into JSON is by using the class `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`, creating an instance and calling `.Serialize(<your-serializable-object>)`.

**Edit**: Added the following (working) example...

*ASPX* page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function doTest( ) {
        try {
            PageMethods.test(theForm.qty.value, function( result ) {
                var  str = '';
                for ( var  key in result ) {
                    str += '\t{ '+ key +': '+ result[ key ] +' }\n';
                }
                alert('Page Method returned the following result:\n'+ (str || "{ }"));
            }, function( ex ) {
                alert('Page Method returned the following "'+ ex.get_exceptionType() +'" exception:\n'+ ex.get_message());
            });
        } catch( err ) {
            alert('Failed to execute Page Method:\n'+ err);
        }
    } // void doTest()
// ]]>
</script>
···
<form runat="server" id="form">
  <asp:scriptmanager runat="server" enablepagemethods="true" />

  <fieldset id="forma">
    <legend>WebMethod Test</legend>
    <label for="qty">
      Number of elements (>= 0):
      <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="5" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Push the button!" onclick="doTest(this)" />
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

And, on your *code behind*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Tests {

    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page {

        [WebMethod]
        static public IDictionary<string,string> test( int length ) {
            if ( 0 > length ) {
                throw  new ArgumentException( "Length cannot be less than zero", "length" );
            }
            var  result = new Dictionary<string,string>( length );
            for ( int  i = 0;  i < length;  i ++ ) {
                result.Add(i.ToString(), Char.ConvertFromUtf32(65 + i) +"|"+ Char.ConvertFromUtf32(97 + i));
            }
            return  result;
        } // IDictionary<string,string> test( int )

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show me a sample code to demonstrate on how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Working (basic) example added. Note that I used a `Dictionary<string,string>` collection, which is *serializable* by default; if you use your own type you will need to mark it with the `Serializable` attribute.

Comment: tnx void! It works for me. 1 vote and marked it as the answer :)